# Calculate the total value of all values returned from a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop which is going through a list of IPS, connecting to a device, finding a specific value, calculating how many times this value is present, and then printing the number of times it is found.

I achieve this by using the `len()` function.

See below code:

```
for line in IPS:
    try:
        IPS = line.strip()
        device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=IPS, username=username,
                                password=password)
        connectedregex = len(re.findall(r"connected", output))
        notconnectregex = len(re.findall(r"notconnect", output))
        errdisable = len(re.findall(r"errdisable", output))
        print(connectedregex, notconnectregex, errdisable)
```

The above code will output as an example:

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
```

What I would like to do, is at the end, add all these values together and just print the total, so the above would actually print as: (for each value 1+2 = 3)

```
3, 3, 3
```

I have tried using `sum()`, and taking my print statement outside the `for` loop, however this does not work.

Comment: you're iterating and assigning to the same variable `IPS`.

Comment: Why are you overriding the variable you're iterating over? While it might turn out ok (Python creates an iterator and iterates over that behind the scenes), it is certainly not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly easily by using the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function in conjunction with [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

I can't run the code in your question of course, but here's some sample code that should give you the idea of how to do something similar:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


IPS = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]

totals = []
for line in IPS:
    connected, notconnect, errdisable = line
    print(connected, notconnect, errdisable)
    totals = [sum(values) for values in
                zip_longest(totals, (connected, notconnect, errdisable),
                            fillvalue=0)]

print()
print('totals:', totals)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5

totals: [6, 9, 12]
```